# corresponding commands from batch file to vbsript

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I trying to go from cmd script to vbscript in MS window xp

cmd code yes works

```
set home_=%~dp0

set part001=part001
set part002=part002
set part003=part003
set part004=part004

::get the dir in part001
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s/b/o:n/a:d ^"%home%%part001%\^"') do (
echo show have dir path
echo %%A
pause
)
echo to the end
pause
goto :eof
```

to vbscript

the part I do not know to convert are those that are foramtted as **cmd{cmd codeing}**

```
dim strHome as strimg =cmd{[%~dp0]}

dim strPart001 as sting = part001
dim strPart002 as sting = part002
dim strPart003 as sting = part003
dim strPart004 as sting = part004

'get the dir in part001
Dim objFSo, objFile
Set objFSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set objDirPart001list = objFS.getfolder(strHome&strPart001\)
set subDirPart001list = objDirPart001list.SubFolders
for each  subDirPart001Name in subDirPart001list
    WScript.Echo show dir path
    WScript.Echo part
    cmd{pause}
    )
cmd{pause}
```

what are the corresponding vbscript commands for:

- %~dp0
- pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%~dp0` is a so-called magic command but more technically this method is known as variable substition.  The %*n* variables are used to reference the command line parameters of the script.  The most common, `%0` will return the full path to the script that is executing.  The d and p are special modifiers that will return the drive and path portion of that path, respectively.  There is also n which returns the filename portion as well as [others](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).  These modifiers can be combined as necessary.  So the `%~dp0` command will return the full drive and path to the directory where the executing script resides.  To do this in VBScript, you can use any of the following that rely on the WScript Object's ScriptFullName method:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = objFso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

Or

```
strPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName))
```

Or my favorite:

```
Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")
```

The `pause` command is used to stop the command interpreter and prompt the user to press any key to continue.  This is typically done so that the user has time to read the information in the command window before it closes. Here's a subroutine to do that in CScript.  (For WScript, you would just use a simple MessageBox.)

```
Sub Pause
    WScript.StdOut.Write "Press any key to continue . . . "
    WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  If you found this answer to be complete, please click the checkmark next to it to mark it as accepted.